# Azure CLI aksManagedNodeOSUpgradeSchedule not upgrading

Tags: azure, azure-aks, node-pools

I have a node pool that I have configured to have an upgrade window of Thursday, start time: 20:00, UTC Offset -07:00, on an intervalWeeks of 1 and a duration of 8 hours.  This is the second week that I have checked to see if the version on the day following the upgrade schedule has resulted in an upgrade. I see no changes.

With the cli `az aks show` command and `--query "agentPoolProfiles[*].{name: name, image:nodeImageVersion }" --output table`

```
Name       Image
---------  ----------------------------------------
<redacted>  AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202307.27.0
```

The cli `az aks nodepool get-upgrade`s with the query of `--query "{ most_recent_node_version: latestNodeImageVersion, upgrades: upgrades }" --output table`

```
Most_recent_node_version
----------------------------------------
AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202308.10.0
```

Or, the raw JSON of:

```
{
  "id": <redacted>,
  "kubernetesVersion": "1.26.6",
  "latestNodeImageVersion": "AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202308.10.0",
  "name": "default",
  "osType": "Linux",
  "resourceGroup": <redacted>,
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/agentPools/upgradeProfiles",
  "upgrades": null
}
```

Are my queries telling me that my agent pool has a version of AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202307.27.0 and the most recent version is AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202308.10.0.

Shouldn't this be upgrading, if I am on week 2 of the following node os upgrade schedule?

```
{
    "id": <redacted>,
    "maintenanceWindow": {
      "durationHours": 8,
      "notAllowedDates": null,
      "schedule": {
        "absoluteMonthly": null,
        "daily": null,
        "relativeMonthly": null,
        "weekly": {
          "dayOfWeek": "Thursday",
          "intervalWeeks": 1
        }
      },
      "startDate": "2023-08-29",
      "startTime": "22:00",
      "utcOffset": "-07:00"
    },
    "name": "aksManagedNodeOSUpgradeSchedule",
    "notAllowedTime": null,
    "resourceGroup": <redacted>,
    "systemData": null,
    "timeInWeek": null,
    "type": null
  }
```

I'm expecting `latestNodeImageVersion` to match `nodeImageVersion` from my two different az cli commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your `autoUpgradeProfile` look like when running the `az aks show` command on your cluster?

Also, what version of Kubernetes are you currently running?

If it is a version that is no longer supported by AKS (n-2 versions), then you'd have to get k8s upgraded to a supported version then the auto-updates should work after that.

Comment: hrm, it seems doing the aksmanagednodeosupgradeschedule things did not result in nodeOsUpgradeProfile being set`{
  "autoUpgradeProfile": {
    "nodeOsUpgradeChannel": null,
    "upgradeChannel": "stable"
  }
}`

Comment: Updated to `{
  "autoUpgradeProfile": {
    "nodeOsUpgradeChannel": "NodeImage",
    "upgradeChannel": "stable"
  }
}`, but still not showing upgrades available`{
  "most_recent_node_version": "AKSUbuntu-2204gen2containerd-202308.22.0",
  "upgrades": null
}` maybe during the upgrade window this week something may change :\

Comment: This was indeed the problem, after checking on upgrades this morning the nodepool is now as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [github- blog](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/releases) by *KAARTHIKEYAN* -   Kubernetes version 1.24 is now deprecated. Azure Linux image has been updated to  [AzureLinux-202308.22.0](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/blob/2023-08-27/vhd-notes/AzureLinux/202308.22.0.txt). As you have updated your Kubernetes version to 1.26.6 but image 7.27.0 is not updated.

To update your agent pool version automatically to the most recent version check the below steps:

Creating Kubernetes cluster, you can view automatic upgrade **Enabled with node image** this will update node os to the latest available image. Whenever new image is available for upgrade aks will upgrade automatically. But it's does not update Kubernetes version like below:

[image]

Now when I check the node pool It shows latest updated node pool like below:

```
az aks nodepool show --resource-group  <RGName> --cluster-name <clusterName> --nodepool-name userpool
```

[image]

In portal:

[image]